# How to make a identity server 6 client for a Xamarin forms shell application with login and registration

Tags: api, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, duende-identity-server

Hi I am creating an app with a registration and login system which stores the user credentials in a Postgres database and the profile photos in an Minio objects storage system. I have created an API to abstract away the database stuff from the user and now I want to protect the API, however this seems to be a harder task than I thought it would be...

I have tried following multiple tutorials and QuickStart's for different solutions but I'm currently following the QuickStart for Identity server 6. Yet I'm not able to figure out how to make a client for my Xamarin forms shell .Net 6 application. Could someone give me an example or walk me through how to make one? I would like it to be able to log in and register a new user.

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  This is far too broad to be considered on topic for SO.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure how to be more specific as the problem I'm having is quite a general one but I cant seem to find a solution specific to me.